# array sum is returning 0 as result

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array in this manner.

```
array(16)
[0] => float(0.3704)
[1] => float(0.1103)
[2] => float(0.1745)
[3] => float(0.2687)
[4] => int(0)
[5] => float(0.4157)
[6] => float(0.2125)
[7] => float(0.2202)
[8] => float(0.2138)
[9] => float(0.2238)
[10] => float(0.1373)
[11] => float(0.2128) 
[12] => float(0.1522)
[13] => float(0.1266)
[14] => float(0.0556)
[15] => float(0.4103)
```

What I am doing is looping is this

```
$gp=array();
$test = array_sum($gp);
foreach ( $summary as $oemName => $oemValues ){
$gp[]                   +=  $oemValues->gross_profit_percent;
}
var_dump($test); die();
```

When I try to do array_sum, i get int(0)back, has anybody ran into this?

Comment: What do you expect `$gp` to be when you call `array_sum()` at the second line?

Comment: @Ivar when I var dump $gp i get the values in the arrays show in the example. (associative array).

Comment: That is after your foreach-loop. But your `array_sum()` is _before_ the foreach-loop. What do you think `$gp` is at that point?

Comment: @Ivar duh! this is what happens when you code in the morning sometimes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an array in that manner - `$gp = array();` - you set it to an empty array before calling `array_sum`.

That'll give you `0`.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you create a new array using `array()` and you get `sum` in the next line. so that it returns 0 as a sum because the sum of an empty array is 0 so try to get the sum and after `foreach` loop and add [array_push()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to inside of `foreach`

```
$gp=array();
foreach ( $summary as $oemName => $oemValues ){
 array_push($gp,$oemValues->gross_profit_percent);
}
$test = array_sum($gp);
var_dump($gp)//for print array
var_dump($test); //for print sum
```